# significance of "for they had + third form of verb"

Tags: meaning

I want to know the meaning of the phrase "for they had". While watching movies, I have come across the sentence. It was like " for they had created a world with no chaos........ What does this "for they had" mean ?

Comment: Please provide more context: the full sentence and what's said before and after it.

Comment: for they had can mean: because they had, but it sounds old-fashioned.

Answer (score 2):

When used as a conjunction, as is likely in your half-remembered example, *for* means *because* or *since*.

> I was very interested to see this species of wombat, for I had never seen such an example before.

This means the same thing as

> I was very interested to see this species of wombat, since I had never seen such an example before.

or

> I was very interested to see this species of wombat, because I had never seen such an example before.